# Cвой дизайн элементов формы

Tags: css3, jquery, html5

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать 1) свой дизайн выпадающего списка как на фото 2) что это за двойной ползунок такой? 3) как сделать свой дизайн такого ползунка? Вот фото: http://gyazo.com/274cebb7993121fdccf01bad08d2bd9a.png
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Свой дизайн и исполнение выпадающего списка и ползунка можно сделать с помощью JS и CSS. Пример ползунка и как он сделан можно посмотреть на Яндекс.Маркете.

Comment: спасибо, а более подробный ответ у вас есть?

Comment: @jackair Насколько более подробный ответ вас бы устроил? Готовые слайдер и select на jsfiddle? Увы, это запрещено правилами ("Не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за деньги какую-либо работу, связанную с программированием").

Answer (score 0):

Выпадающий список можно подглядеть у меня, специально делал пример для участника этого форума: [Свой select](http://lampacore.ru/2012/11/23/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-select-html-javascript-css/)

На счет ползунка, возьмите готовый вариант с использованием jQuery UI, благо jQuery у вас уже есть: [jQuery UI Range slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)